# dynamic to static url AND removing the dynamic

Tags: .htaccess, dynamic, static, url-rewriting

**I want to change alle dynamic url's to static ones, 
but after rewriting the dynamic url's are still responding/available.**

What did I do =>

I found this Tool for SEO:
http://www.webconfs.com/url-rewriting-tool.php

I entered this:
.../filmdetails.html?var=ich_einfach_unverbesserlich_ii

Then I put into my .htaccess this:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^filmdetails/(.*)/$ filmdetails.html?var=$1
```

Works, but now I got a problem: This URL is still available and should not be: .../filmdetails.html?var=ich_einfach_unverbesserlich_ii

How do I get rid of the dynamic url's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule only rewrites the nicer looking URL to the one with a query string. Rules only work from a "pattern" -> "target" way, the mapping won't magically work the other way. You'll have to create a separate rule in order to redirect the browser:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /filmdetails\.html\?var=([^&\ ]+)&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /filmdetails/%2/?%3 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Copy & Pasted your solution and it works, but got further questions.
First, can u explain the code? whats the get head thing, very cryptic all, I hate htaccess because of that. I need to understand it because I have to be sure what it does.
Secondly, Is it ok, that the internal links are like "/filmdetails.html?var=ich_einfach_unverbesserlich_ii"

Comment: Ok question no. 3: why doesn't it produce a LOOP?

Comment: @JürgenScheffler It doesn't loop because the condition checks the *actual HTTP request*. This is the first line of an HTTP request that looks something like: `GET /path/to/file?param=value HTTP/1.1`. This is different from the URI as the URI gets changed by the rewrite engine, but the `${THE_REQUEST}` var is only the actual request. If the browser requested the nicer looking URL, it won't match this rule.

Comment: Thank you! So my code was an URI rewrite and yours a request rewrite.
I do nice URI to dynamic URI
You do dyn URI by headerrequest to nice URI.
Simpled talked. Correct me if I am still wrong. Else all is that and I am glad you helped.

Comment: @JürgenScheffler Both are URI rewrite, it's just the rule above checks against the **Request** instead of the URI. It's simply a way to prevent rewrite looping because you only want to redirect if the actual request has the query string, not the URI.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
#set this to path to your filmdetails.html file (from the document root)
RewriteBase /
#checking if redirect already happened
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_PASSED} !^$
RewriteRule $ - [L]
#Your rewrite rule
RewriteRule ^filmdetails/(.*)/$ filmdetails.html?var=$1 [L,E=PASSED:1]
#redirecting from filmdetails.html with query string ?var=something
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^var=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^filmdetails.html$ filmdetails/%1/? [R]
```

`filmdetails.html?var=something` will be redirected to `filmdetails/something`

Comment: Dont get this, Hopefully Jon Lin's solution is enough for me. Thanks Im ieee, anyways.